# Find all documents not having a keyword in array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, keyword-search

Consider these 3 documents.

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('5b9035e7b93fee6022c31201'),
    'keyword': ['a', 'b']
}, 

{
    '_id': ObjectId('5b9035e7b93fee6022c31202'),
    'keyword': ['a']
}, 

{
    '_id': ObjectId('5b9035e7b93fee6022c31203'),
    'keyword': ['b', 'c']
}
```

I want to match the documents where keyword `a` is not present.

So, the result should be:

```
{
    '_id': ObjectId('5b9035e7b93fee6022c31203'),
    'keyword': ['b', 'c']
}
```

How to do this in mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$nin`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) query operator

```
db.collection.find({ "keyword": { "$nin": ["a"] }})
```

or either [**`$ne`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) query operator

```
db.collection.find({ "keyword": { "$ne": "a" }})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried `nin` earlier, but haven't passed as an array. It works now.